# passing values to a custom script in wordpress via url

Tags: wordpress

I m customizing cforms plugin in wordpress and i have added a report that fetch all records from database and display them in a table. This is how reports link look like.

```
http://localhost/er/wp-admin/admin.php?page=cforms/cforms-report.php
```

Now i want to make a link for each record in each row to delete a record. for this i have passed record's id to my script like this.

```
http://localhost/er/wp-admin/admin.php?page=cforms/cforms-report.php?id=12
```

Also tried this

```
http://localhost/er/wp-admin/admin.php?page=cforms/cforms-report.php/12
```

in both cases i get this on clicking delete link.

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.
```

Kindly tell me how can i GET values in my script from url.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anyone looking forward to this kind of silly question can get help from this answer lols.. all you have to do is

```
http://localhost/er/wp-admin/admin.php?page=cforms/cforms-report.php&id=12
```

and you can get id in your script.. This was a very basic mistake and i could not figure out for hours.